# R, Xpath, Scrape

Tags: r, xpath, scrape

I want to scrape a website using Xpath references and R.
I am new to this, but as far as I learned, I write the following code,,

```
 A <- "http://www.strompreis.elcom.admin.ch/ShowCat.aspx?placeNumber=5661&OpID=2&Period=2015"
 doc <- htmlParse(A)
 A <- xpathApply(A,path="//tr[1]/td/span",fun=xmlAttrs)
```

However, I got the following error,

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I am interested in scaping the following xpath: //tr[1]/td/span
What is the problem? What's worng with the code?

Comment: You could also try package [rvest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html)  Maybe that way will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rvest, this seems to work:

```
library(rvest)
A="http://www.strompreis.elcom.admin.ch/ShowCat.aspx?placeNumber=5661&OpID=2&Period=2015"
A %>% html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//tr[1]/td/span") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You put A instead of doc in the xpathApply part...

```
A="http://www.strompreis.elcom.admin.ch/ShowCat.aspx?placeNumber=5661&OpID=2&Period=2015"
doc <- htmlParse(A)
xpathApply(doc,path="//tr[1]/td/span",fun=xmlAttrs)
```